# Array to object with based on given key

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array declared which uses the `Object.assign`:

```js
var obj = [{
  id: 1,
  value: 'abc'
}, {
  id: 2,
  value: 'xyz'
}];

console.log(Object.assign({}, obj));
```

it's getting transformed as,

```
{ 
    '0': { id: 1, value: 'abc' }, 
    '1': { id: 2, value: 'xyz' } 
}
```

However I need to have this as, (here the `1` and `2` represents the `id` attribute of my object)

```
{
        '1': {id: 1, value: 'abc'},
        '2': {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}
}
```

I've tried few, but had no luck, Can someone shed some light?

Comment: Why do you need it to be one and not zero? The first key in an ordinal array is typically going to be 0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could map the objects in an object with the wanted key and assign it to a single object.

```js
var objects = [{ id: 1, value: 'abc' }, { id: 2, value: 'xyz' }],
    result = Object.assign(...objects.map(o => ({ [o.id]: o })));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `reduce()` method with `Object.assign`.

```js
var obj = [{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}];
var result = obj.reduce((r, e) => Object.assign(r, {[e.id]: e}), {});
console.log(result)
```

Note that we are passing a reference of each object in a array and not creating new objects, but you can change that with object assign on `e` or you can use spread syntax like so:

```
Object.assign(r, {[e.id]: {...e}})
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do that, and there is no need for `Object.assign` here:

```js
var obj = [{id: 1, value: 'abc'}, {id: 2, value: 'xyz'}];

let result = obj.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.id] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `.id` to be the key, you can use `reduce` and use `Object.assign`

```js
let obj = [{id: 1,value: 'abc'}, {id: 2,value: 'xyz'}];

let result = obj.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.id]: v}), {});

console.log(result);
```